# How to multiplex tcp stream to multiple websocket clients with Nginx/Openresty?

Tags: sockets, nginx, tcp, lua, openresty

I have a setup where some TCP clients connect to a program on my server. I am trying to insert nginx in between so that the tcp connection goes from client -> nginx -> program. This is so that I can tap into the stream and let websocket clients request one of the stream's data.

I have been able to create a TCP listening socket with https://github.com/openresty/stream-lua-nginx-module which receives data and then connects to the external program with ngx.socket.tcp().
And also I'm using lua-resty-websocket to create a websocket server (each session needs to connect to one of the streams, and multiple such sessions may connect to a single stream).

What would be a way for the websocket context to connect to that stream?

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with websocket client without any changes in the external program, you put an nginx in between to be the 'transletor' ?

If so, maybe https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-websocket will be helpful.

Comment: I'm already using that, I accidentally deleted that in an edit to the original question, will add that now.